# How to create database name with SQLiteOpenHelper constructor?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am trying to define a Sqlite database name and table name with the SqliteOpenHelper constructor when it is called. For my Android application, I want the user to be able to input the desired database name and table name that they want, and capture it with an editText then pass those values in as parameters to the constructor. I am needing some guidance on how to go about it. Pretty much all of the tutorials or examples I have found are all showing the database name and table name to be hard-coded. If anyone has some examples of how to go about it, that would be great. Many thanks.

Comment: You can create a constructor of your Sqliteopenhelper and pass the required params and then call `super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION)` You can also pass table name